# Nginx Configuration to Apache

Tags: apache, nginx

I'm trying to port an conf file from Nginx to Apache. Right now my collegue running with Nginx, but I use Apache instead of Nginx.

The nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name MY_SERVER_NAME;
root /DIR_PROJECT/web;

    //Angular
    location / {
             root /DIR_PROJECT/web/front;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/(uploads)(/.*)$ {
            root /DIR_PROJECT/app/data;
    }

    //Symfony
    location ~ ^/(assets|bundles)(/.*)$ {
            #try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
            try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 32k;
            fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
            include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_log /DIR_PROJECT/app/logs/error.log;
    access_log /DIR_PROJECT/app/logs/access.log;
}
```

I want change it to apache configuration. How I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: People migrate the other way, not sure why you want to use Apache. Nginx config are much easier to write and easily understandable. 

You can try a online converter and see if it works for you 
 https://labs.gidix.de/nginx/

Comment: I use Apache because I want have the same configuration of my client.

Comment: Use this converter and then create a new config, if any specific issue then post your converted config and ask specific questions