# nginx configuration to apache httpd conf

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to convert this config snippet to apache. Don't understand what the location/add header tags will get converted to

```
location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    # Security based headers
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
}

# reverse proxy for xyz
location /zyz/v1 {
    proxy_pass         https://localhost:4855/zyz/v1;
}
```

Comment: Have a problem similar to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780526/nginx-configuration-to-apache

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this is Apache configuration that you need to add to apache2.conf/httpd.conf, NOT TO .htaccess.

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Headet set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/zyz/v1(/|$) https://localhost:4885/xyz/v1 [P,L]
# OR
#ProxyPass /zyz/v1 https://localhost:4885/xyz/v1
```

`Header` requires mod_headers to be enabled.

`Rewrite*` requires mod_rewrite to be enabled.

Also, for `Rewrite*`, when you are adding outside a `<VirtualHost>` section, you will need to add `RewriteEngine On` to all the virtualhosts, and add `RewriteOptions InheritDown` below **this** `RewriteEngine On`.

Change `[P,L]` to `[P,QSA,L]` if you also want to pass query string to the backend server. You need to enable `mod_proxy` for `[P]`. I believe you would also want to enable `mod_proxy_http` since you want apache to communicate to the backend server using HTTP.

Comment: Thaks for the detail answer along with the module names.

The first part i understand . But for # reverse proxy for xyz
location /zyz/v1 {
    proxy_pass         https://localhost:4855/zyz/v1;
}

should not it transalte to 

`Proxypass /zyz/v1  https://localhost:4885/xyz/v1`

Comment: @MadhusudanSamantray, Thats fine too. its `ProxyPass` not `Proxypass`, I am sure

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It is ProxyPass . Noted